# React with Typescript: Wrong pointer when passing object as props after shuffle function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, card

I am building a card game to learn React using typescript and I have encountered this bug I don't know how to fix. I have the following classes

A card class which holds a simple card object:

```
class Card {
    private readonly _face: number
    private readonly _suit: string
    private readonly _id: string

    constructor(face: number, suit: string,  id: string) {
        if (!(1 <= face && face <= 13)) {
        throw new Error("Suit must be in range 1 - 13")
        }
        if ("SHDC".indexOf(suit) === -1) {
            throw new Error("Suit of card must be either S, H, D or C");
        }
        this._face = face
        this._suit = suit
        this._id = id
    }

    get id(): string {
        return this._id;
    }

    get string(): string {
        return this._face + this._suit
    }
}

export default Card;
```

The cardDeck class which holds a set of cards:

```
import Card from "./card";

class CardDeck {
    private _cards: Card[]

    constructor() {
        this._cards = this.resetDeck(1)
        this.shuffleRandomly()
    }

    private resetDeck(numberOfDecks: number): Card[] {
        const cards: Card[] = []
        const suits = "SHDC";
        let counter: number = 0
        for (let i = 0; i < numberOfDecks; i++) {
            for (let suitIndex = 0; suitIndex < 4; suitIndex++) {
                for (let face = 1; face < 14; face++) {
                    const card = new Card(face, suits.charAt(suitIndex), String(counter));
                    cards.push(card)
                    counter++
                }
            }
        }
        return cards
    }

    draw(): Card {
        if (this.cardCount < 1) {
            this._cards = this.resetDeck(10)
        }
        return this._cards.pop()!
    }

    get cardCount(): number {
        return this._cards.length;
    }

    private shuffleRandomly() {
        let shuffledDeck: Card[] = [];
        while(this.cardCount > 0) {
            let index = Math.floor(Math.random()*this.cardCount)
            shuffledDeck.push(this._cards[index])
            this._cards.splice(index, 1)
        }
        this._cards = shuffledDeck
}
}

export default CardDeck;
```

A displayCard class which will render the card later, but for the moment it only logs the card string it's going to render to the console:

```
import Card from "./card";
import React from "react";


interface Props {
    card: Card
}

function DisplayCard(props:Props) {
    console.log(props.card.string)
    return (
        <div />
    )
}

export default DisplayCard
```

Finally my App class:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import CardDeck from "./cardDeck";
import DisplayCard from "./displayCard";

function App() {
    const deck = new CardDeck()
    const card = deck.draw()
    console.log(card.string)

    return (
      <div>
          <DisplayCard card={card} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

---

Now the problem is that the const card variable changes from when I console.log() it in the App class to when I do it in the DisplayCard class, even though it's supposed to be the same object. Just now the App class prints "6S" while the DisplayCard class prints "8D".

If i remove the shuffleRandomly() call in the CardDeck constructor, they reference the same card, but when I include the shuffle function they reference different cards. It seems as though the const card variable gets a pointer before the constructor is finished shuffling, and doesn't update it after the deck finishes shuffling. Does anyone see what I do wrong or how I can fix this?